# Waiting a process to terminate to start another one

Tags: bash, loops

I wanted to take out the maximum performance of my machine. So, I attached all available colors to a single process, being this one dependent on an iteration.

```
#! /bin/bash
[ -z "`echo $BIN`" ] && BIN="mpirun -np 12 /home/path"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5;do
# setting input 
$BIN &
mv output_file output_file_$i
done
```

When I open my nohup.out file I got the message that my output_file is not there. I understand it but I want the process to finish, move that file and continue with different input parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not waiting long enough between starting `mpirun` and moving the log file to a new name. These two lines:

```
$BIN &
mv output_file output_file_$i
```

This runs your BIN and then immediately tries to rename `output_file`, probably so quickly that the file has not even been created yet!

Instead of `$BIN &` why not `$BIN --output-filename output_file_$i &` ? And then you don't need the `mv` command at all.

So the whole script would become

```sh
#!/bin/bash
[ -z "`echo $BIN`" ] && BIN="mpirun -np 12 /home/path"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  $BIN --output-file output_file_$i &
done
```

Comment: The ideia seems good but it does not wait the first iteration (process) to be concluded to start the next.

Comment: @MiguelCardoso :  then remove the `&` from the `$BIN ...` line. `&` means **to run in the background** so other programs can start running immediately. In this case you don't need/want that feature. Good luck to all.

Comment: @MiguelCardoso I assumed you'd put the `&` there on purpose, deliberately so that it doesn't wait. It's unusual to use `&` in a for loop unless you're trying to make things run simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

this would block your terminal until your process finished and would be considered a foreground process with no user interaction. The point here being whether the process blocks the execution of other processes until it terminates.

you can make a foreground process into a background one by adding `&` at the end of your command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z "`echo $BIN`" ] && BIN="mpirun -np 12 /home/path"
for i in {1..5}; do $BIN --output-file output_file_$i; done
```